# Is there any 'sudo' command for Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, privileges

I always work on a non-administrator account on my Windows computer. Sometimes I need to install programs which requires administrator access. As I mostly use the Windows command prompt, is there a Windows command to escalate privileges, similar to the Linux terminal command `sudo`?

Comment: I believe the term you are looking for is "elevated" access. Even though your credentials have admin permission, processes under your credentials don't have admin permissions until you "sudo" the command.  In Windows, they call it "elevate".

Comment: @IGRACH not on my powershell...

Comment: I use this `doskey sudo= runas /user:Administrator "cmd /k cd \"%cd%\" & $*"`

Comment: [gsudo](https://superuser.com/a/1499989/45898) works in cmd/powershell/windows terminal and has some nice features.

Comment: This may be old news now but I run windows 10 with [windows-subsystem-for-linux enabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). For my wsl terminal I use Ubuntu. I never thought I would go for something like this as a linux user but it's actually pretty handy, plays nice with [VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) as well.

Comment: Microsoft just added "Sudo for Windows." 
See https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/sudo/
The [run as](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command will continue to be supported and enables running programs as other users, including but not limited to as administrator, which Sudo for Windows does not yet support.

Answer (score 297, accepted):

The [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) command.

```
runas [{/profile|/noprofile}] [/env] [/netonly] [/smartcard] [/showtrustlevels] [/trustlevel] /user:UserAccountName program
```

Just run:

```
runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd
```

to start a command shell as a administrator

Comment: You might find you want the profile loaded (e.g. including environment variables) for any extended use. In which case drop the `/noprofile`.

Comment: You also have to make sure that the Administrator account has a password. Otherwise you get an error 1327, "user account restriction. Possible reasons are blank passwords not allowed,..."

Comment: This is not working for me. After I typed my password the command prompt is closed.

Comment: The "Account is disabled" checkbox on the user properties must be unchecked for this command to work.

Comment: @Jonas, you might have a renamed Admin account. I had the same issue

Comment: isn't this asking for the Administrator's password? sudo is asking for ***your*** password!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is seriously outdated.  `Runas` merely runs commands under a different set of credentials. Even though your credentials have admin permissions, it doesn't mean all processes under your credentials run as admin.

Comment: Can the script provide the password?

Comment: @naxa Yeah, it's not exactly sudo. But you can change `/user:Administrator` to `/user:YourLoginName` and do the same thing as sudo, of course. Don't quite understand @surfasb 's comment. When would this bite you? I've successfully used this trick to edit files that are only editable by an admin (eg `runas /noprofile /user:myUserName "C:\path\to\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe C:\some\file.cfg"`)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It just asks for password (whether MyLoginName or the Administrator) and just runs the command normally. I've tested it by running `taskmgr` and even after entering password it says "*740: The requested operation requires elevation.*". Running `calc` works as it doesn't require elevation.

Comment: @surfasb what if you launch whatever program you want from cmd, after doing runas /user:Administrator?

Comment: +1 for "outdated" since runas can't bypass UAC. Instead,  press Windows button, type cmd, and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: @barlop: You should look up how UAC works. The Administrator account, by default, auto elevates process to Admin permissions. It's a coincidence that it works with the Administrator account. Use any other account in the Administators **group** with *runas* and your program won't get Admin permissions by default.

Comment: https://chocolatey.org/packages/Sudo

Comment: This is elevation of a user account in Administrators; sudo is another thing.

Answer (score 145):

**[Elevate](http://code.kliu.org/misc/elevate/)** - *"executes a command with UAC privilege elevation. This is useful for working inside command prompts or with batch files."* It's not the same as `sudo`, it changes the executing user to Administrator, but its syntax is a lot more straightforward to use than `runas`, and it can keep the current directory, enabling the use of relative paths.

```
Synopsis:
  elevate [(-c | -k) [-n] [-u]] [-w] command

Options:
  -c  Launches a terminating command processor; equivalent to "cmd /c command".
  -k  Launches a persistent command processor; equivalent to "cmd /k command".
  -n  When using -c or -k, do not pushd the current directory before execution.
  -u  When using -c or -k, use Unicode; equivalent to "cmd /u".
  -w  Waits for termination; equivalent to "start /wait command".
```

Elevate's purpose isn't to work around or bypass UAC (User Account Control), but to work with it. As long as UAC is enabled there *has* to be some kind of prompt at *some* point in the process. If you need to get rid of prompting altogether you have to [disable UAC](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-uac.html).

The pain point Elevate alleviates is escalating a particular process from a non-privileged shell and then carrying on as normal. Without this you need to start a privileged command prompt with *right-click > "Run as Administrator"* before attempting the privileged command, which can't be easily scripted.

This works well with *"Elevate without prompting"* in `secpol.msc`. Together, they do the same as `%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` in sudo

A known limitation is that it does not return the error code from the program it is elevating.

If your muscle memory is stuck on *sudo*, create an alias using [Doskey](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html):
`doskey sudo=elevate -w`

or batchfile in PATH:
`@elevate -w %*`

Elevate is 3rd party tool written by [Johannes Passing](https://jpassing.com/). It's an 11kb download and portable (no install needed): http://code.kliu.org/misc/elevate/

Comment: This goes perfect with "Elevate without prompting" in secpol.msc. Together, they do the same as `%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` in sudo.

Comment: @sayap, just to be clear, do you mean this: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-uac.html?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. From my limited testing, it works straight away without having to restart Windows.

Comment: there's a similar program with the same name here: http://wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/03/27/elevate-a-process-at-the-command-line-in-vista.aspx

Comment: The only trouble I find with elevate (v1.3.0) is that it does not return the error code from the program it is elevating.

Comment: Sudo.bat : `@elevate %*` => profit!

Comment: -1 this requires elaboration. I just tried `C:\>elevate dir` and it caused a popup prompting me if I want to elevate. That isn't very useful in a script.

Comment: @barlop: elevate's purpose isn't to work around or bypass UAC (User Account Control), but to work with it. As long as UAC is enabled there *has* to be some kind of prompt at _some_ point in the process. If you need to get rid of prompting altogether you have to disable UAC (see 2nd comment). The problem elevate solves is escalating a particular process from a non-privileged shell, and then carrying on as normal. Without this you need to start a privileged command prompt with right-click "Run as Administrator", which can't be scripted, before attempting the privileged command.

Comment: @barlop, ok. I see I don't understand the nature of your complaint, and don't know how else to attempt to address it.

Comment: `alias sudo='elevate -w'`

Comment: Open explorer.exe as another credentials user and as administrator?

Comment: @Kiquenet that's the same approach as `runas` in other answers, with similar results and differences to *elevate*, isn't it?

Comment: Would be nice to mention that it's an external utility, missing OOTB.

Comment: This is elevation of a user account in Administrators; sudo is another thing.

Comment: Bowing to the wisdom of the crowd: post edited to declare it's a download (and credit the maker by name); Also incorporated other comment info.

Comment: @massimo: see 2nd sentence ;-)

Comment: 'elevate' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Trying on Win10

Comment: @AdamBajger you need to download it first, see last sentence in answer. If you've done that it needs to be put in [tag:path]

Answer (score 69):

You can use the [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) command which is kind of similar, or you can check out the [sudo for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudowin/) project over at [SourceForge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge) which adds a sudo command.

The difference is subtle:

Let's say you have two users. Bob is a normal user and James is an administrator.

If you log in as Bob and use "runas james acommand" the command is run as if it was run by James, so it accesses James' user settings and any user changes go into James *My Documents* & settings folders, etc. So if you are installing an application, say, it will be installed as James, not as Bob.

If on the other hand Bob does "sudo acommand" the command is still run as Bob, but with elevated permissions - just like the Linux sudo command. To prevent any user from being able to sudo you have to define a sudoers user group that contains the list of the normal users that have permission to elevate using sudo. The users still have to provide credentials before elevation.

Sometimes the difference isn't important, sometimes it is, and I find that both commands can be useful.

Comment: Are you sure? When I run sudo in ubuntu, if my current theme is in `~/.themes` then the sudo-ed application will not be able to access that theme, because it's not in `/home/root/.themes`, and will use the default ugly gtk theme.

Comment: @hasen j - your issue is just because ~/.themes evaluates before the command is run (and thus before it switches over to root).

Comment: Another solution, except hosted on GitHub, is windosu: https://github.com/tehsenaus/windosu I just found it, and it seems to work great. Favorite thing is it's super easy to install. Just "npm install -g windosu".

Comment: This is elevation of a user account in Administrators; sudo is another thing.

Comment: @Massimo, can you explain the difference.

Answer (score 42):

You can also use the [Script Elevation PowerToys](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.06.elevation.aspx).

Comment: Awesome - exactly what I was looking for. I didn't want to run as a command has a different user, only to run it with elevated privileges.

Comment: Exactly the right solution for this problem!  Who wants Runas with its messy syntax?

Comment: I've often wished the elevate command were built into windows. It's a fantastic tool.

Comment: there's now an [Elevation PowerToys collection](http://blogs.technet.com/b/elevationpowertoys/) by the same author from which [Creating a Self-Elevating Script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/elevationpowertoys/archive/2010/06/20/creating-a-self-elevating-script.aspx) is particularly relevant.

Comment: @nhinkle can you do elevate command such that it suppresses the popup asking if you want to elevate it?

Comment: @barlop of course not. That would defeat the purpose of UAC.

Comment: @nhinkle limiting the techie user in efficiency / demanding his attention for the meanial task of confirmation to run elevated,  isn't exactly its goal(its goal is to prevent malicious attack, not elongate the process for legit things), but obviously it's something that it could be argued it must unfortunately do. Now though, if any program could run elevated in an automated way(no permission required), would you want it destroyed, for it hath defeated "the purpose of UAC"?

Comment: @barlop the whole point of UAC is that you can't run elevated without getting the user's permission. If you could just type `elevate whatever.exe` and have it run elevated, then it would be trivial for an attacker to run `elevate nasty-virus.exe`. It's an inherent requirement of UAC that confirmation occur somehow. It can't ask for confirmation in the command window, because the confirmation must run on an isolated secure desktop to prevent other software from injecting keystrokes.

Comment: @nhinkle i'm aware of that and am not disputing that. you didn't quite answer the question I asked you at the end of my comment but it doesn't matter, not important! ;-)

Comment: It seems @barlop does not understand UAC. If you want your script to stop prompting you need to switch UAC off temporarily--which requires at least one prompt at the start of the script. Though I think in newer Windows versions even that became harder. Or maybe run every process from an elevated cmd.

Comment: To only ask once, the script must have a separate component that would then do the administrative actions.

Comment: @nhinkle "because the confirmation must run on an isolated secure desktop to prevent other software from injecting keystrokes"? What??? how is every other OS on the planet able to do this securely?

Answer (score 32):

If you are ready to switch to alternative consoles, there is [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) (I'm the author). One of its features - the ability to run both elevated and non-elevated tabs in the one ConEmu window. Tabs may be started with different credentials too.

For user comfort, there is batch-file [csudo.cmd](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/blob/master/Release/ConEmu/csudo.cmd) (which may be easily adopted to bash). Read full description in [project's wiki](https://conemu.github.io/en/csudo.html). In brief, when you run some command from existing non-elevated tab, for example

```
csudo dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```

ConEmu will starts `dism` in the new elevated console/tab (with preceding UAC prompt in Vista or Login box in XP).

By default `csudo` starts new console in a split (may be changes via editing of `csudo.cmd` contents).

And of course you may rename it to `sudo.cmd` if you like "classic" `sudo` word.

[image: sudo in ConEmu/Windows]

Comment: csudo long ago was included in the ConEmu distribution. No link is needed at all.

Comment: problem here is the new console tab becomes unusable after the sudo'd command. So you can't continue working in the elevated tab, just get a `press enter or esc to exit` message.

Comment: Of course you cant. Even on Unix you are back to non-elevated terminal after `sudo` command is done its work! You are going wrong way.

Comment: 1) if you're gonna open a new window or tab you might as well keep it, let the *user* choose if they want to continue. 2) On my ubuntu I don't have to sudo every time, elevation lasts a few minutes I think. 3) this application has a million options, yet nothing for this? Maybe I'm spoiled.

Answer (score 29):

## Quick method:

Three steps to add sudo.

1. Open PowerShell.
2. Copy the following script (Ctrl+C) and paste it in PowerShell (Alt+Space+E+P):

```
$script_path="$HOME\Documents\Scripts"; if (!(test-path $script_path)) {New-Item -ItemType directory $script_path} if (!(test-path $profile)) { new-item -path $profile -itemtype file -force }". $script_path\sudo.ps1" | Out-File $profile -append; "function sudo(){if (`$args.Length -eq 1){start-process `$args[0] -verb `"runAs`"} if (`$args.Length -gt 1){start-process `$args[0] -ArgumentList `$args[1..`$args.Length] -verb `"runAs`"}}" | Out-File $script_path\sudo.ps1; powershell
```

3. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It will permanently enable `sudo` command in PowerShell.

## Usage:

```
sudo <process-name> [param1 [param2 [param3]]]
```

Examples:

```
sudo explorer
sudo notepad
sudo powershell
sudo cmd
sudo taskmgr
sudo tasklist
sudo taskkill /IM Skype.exe /PID 8496
```

## Long method for learning:

- Read [this article](http://www.ainotenshi.org/710/%E2%80%98sudo%E2%80%99-for-powershell-sorta).
- Read the comments.
- Take a look at [Stephen's git repository](https://github.com/stephenn/powershell_sudo) and the [readme file](https://github.com/stephenn/powershell_sudo/blob/master/readme.rst).

*Note: I mixed the script from both articles to create the aforementioned script. Rather manually pasting the script in notepad I added the `Out-File` statements to save `ps1` and `$profile` files from the script.*

**Tip: If you are not a very big fan of UAC popups (like me), save the following in *.reg file and run it:**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: I love the powershell solution for this question.  This has to be the easiest way to elevate something.  Existing .bat files can easily be converted to POSH

Comment: Got this error on windows 10:
`. : File C:\Users\User\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running
scripts is disabled on this system.`

Comment: @sowrov, see [this article](www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-powershell-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system/). By default PowerShell scripts are disabled on any Windows installation. You need to enable it with this command `set-executionpolicy remotesigned`. Other options besides `remotesigned` are described in [official docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx).

Comment: Readers note this ps script is a wrapper for the `powershell -c start -verb runas program.exe` functionality. Also note you *can't elevate* like this with the cmd prompt (natively). Powershell is the best native option.

Comment: can the same be done in cmd.exe instead of powershell env? powershell does not compute with clink and without clink windows does not compute at all...

Comment: This is elevation of a user account in Administrators; sudo is another thing.

Answer (score 19):

If you're doing this on Windows, then in addition to the Run As command as mentioned in a couple of other answers, there are also ways to do this with the mouse.

If you hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key as you right-click on most executable files in Windows you should notice a few more advanced options. One of these is the "`Run As...`" option (I think it's called "`Run As Administrator`" from Vista onwards).

You can also download a more advanced version of RunAs from Microsoft, called [ShellRunAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361.aspx), this has enhancements over the built-in RunAs command, both in command line and graphical modes, including letting you save account credentials

Comment: This is elevation of a user account in Administrators; sudo is another thing.

Comment: The question was about elevating with command! F.e. from a batch file, when detected that certain operation requires elevation.

Comment: @AnrDaemon I'm surprised to be admonished about the relevance of an answer that I left here a decade ago!

Answer (score 8):

I wrote **gsudo**, a sudo for windows that feels like `*nix sudo` and has a few killer features:

- Run within the current console (attached) without breaking tab-key auto-complete. Or add `-n` to launch in a new window.
- Handles all scenarios reliably to be used on scripts. (ExitCodes, StdIn/Out/Err Redirection/Capture)
- Supports Cmd/PowerShell/PowerShell Core

- Credentials cache: If `gsudo` is invoked several times within minutes it only shows the UAC pop-up once.

[image: gsudo demo]

#### Usage

`gsudo`  Opens an elevated shell in the current console.

`gsudo [options] {command} [arguments]`
Executes the specified command with elevated permissions.

Most relevant **`[options]`**:

- **`-n | --new`**        Starts the command in a **new** console with elevated rights (and returns immediately).
- **`-w | --wait`**       Force wait for the process to end (and return the exitcode).
- **`-s | --system`**     Run As Local System account ("NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM").

#### Installation

- Using Scoop: `scoop install gsudo`
- Using Chocolatey: `choco install gsudo`
- Using Winget: `winget install gsudo`
- Or check the [docs](https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo/) and [latest release](https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo/releases)

Comment: This looks great, but does it rely on the UAC graphical prompt? I am logging in via SSH and wants something that works purely in a command line mode.

Comment: Yes. At least one UAC popup will show up.

Answer (score 4):

[Surun](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http://kay-bruns.de/wp/software/surun/&langpair=de%7Cen&hl=de&safe=active&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&prev=/language_tools) is free, open-source application that allows certain programs to run with administrative rights, without providing a password without changing the user registry or modify environment variables.

When I was using Windows XP this app helps me a lot. [Beta](http://forum.kay-bruns.de/thread/411) works under Windows 7.

Comment: surun does a great job. However sometimes under Windows 8 and 8.1 its defaults aren't ideal. Because it replaces Windows's run as function, you are not able to start a command prompt with right click on the start screen.

Comment: This is the best answer and should be the accepted one. Most of the other answers are about elevation of a user account in Administrators: not sudo.

Answer (score 3):

As you've probably discovered, `runas` will let you run as another user but it cannot do elevation and it doesn't pass current directories, environment variables or long command lines.

[Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm) solves that with a genuine `su` and `sudo`. `su` lets you run a command as another user; `sudo` (actually an alias to `su`) lets you run a command elevated. You can also do both, running elevated as a different user. Current directories, environment variables and long command lines are passed by way of a shared memory handshake between `su` running in the caller's context and a copy of itself running as an interlude with the new credentials that then starts the child. Full disclosure: I'm the author.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution in my view is to leverage powershell to do the work, which is portable and will prompt the user using the UAC.

You can just run this in any shell (cmd or powershell)

```
powershell Start-Process -verb runAs path-to-your.exe "-all -args -in -quotes"
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a chocolatey package for it with the convenient name [sudo](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Sudo). You can install the package with chocolatey using this command:

```shell
choco install -y sudo
```

Then in whatever Windows/MS shell you have to use, you can use `sudo` as expected.

Comment: This is elevation of a user account in Administrators; sudo is another thing.

Answer (score 2):

There is now an official Sudo for Windows. It allows users to run elevated commands directly from unelevated terminal windows.

Sudo is available for Windows 11 builds 26045 and later. If you're on an Insiders build with sudo, you can enable it in the Windows Settings app, on the "Developer Features" page.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/sudo

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I created `wsudo`, [an open-source](https://github.com/noseratio/choco/tree/main/wsudo) `sudo`-like CLI tool for Windows to run programs or commands with elevated rights, **in the context of the current directory**. It's freely available as a [Chocolatey package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/wsudo).

I use it a lot for things like configuring build agents, admin stuff like `sfc /scannow`, `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` or simply for installing/updating my local Chocolatey packages (e.g., `wasudo cup all -y`). Use at your own risk.

## Installation

```
choco install wsudo
```

[Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) must be already installed.

## Purpose

`wsudo` is a Linux `sudo`-like tool for Windows to invoke a program with elevated rights (as Administrator) from a non-admin shell command prompt and keeping its current directory.

This implementation doesn't depend on the legacy Windows Script Host (`CScript`). Instead, it uses a helper PowerShell 5.1 script that invokes `"Start-Process -Wait -Verb runAs ..."` cmdlet. Your system most likely already has PowerShell 5.x installed, otherwise you'll be offered to install it as a dependency.

## Usage

`wsudo` runs a program or an inline command with elevated rights in the current directory. Examples:

```
wsudo .\myAdminScript.bat 
wsudox "del C:\Windows\Temp\*.* && pause"
wasudo cup all -y
wasudox start notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

I often invoke it from the Windows Run box (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), or by typing `wasudo` <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the Windows Explorer address bar (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>). The latter opens an admin command prompt in the Explorer's current folder.

**For more details, visit the [GitHub repro](https://github.com/noseratio/choco/tree/main/wsudo).**

Answer (score 0):

A working `sudo` replacement for Cygwin's `mintty` terminal would be to place the following script in user's PATH:

```
$!/bin/bash
cygstart --action=runas mintty -e `which bash` -lc \"$@\"
```

For me this is the only viable replacement to elevate privileges of programs like `vim` or `cygrunsrv` while working in a terminal on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This script does the job:

```
@echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") > %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@echo args = Right("%*", (Len("%*") - Len("%1"))) >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@echo objShell.ShellExecute "%1", args, "", "runas" >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@cscript //NoLogo %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
```

Save it as `sudo.cmd` then add it to your PATH

Note: the `runas` means in this context "Run as administrator" and not "Run as other user"

[Taken from here](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/142153-sudo-equivalent-for-windows-vista7/) and slightly edited to remove cscript.exe header from output

Comment: This creates a new console. The new window will disappear after the sudo'd command is completed--so you can't even read output.

Comment: Sadly, yes. But it can be used for some basic commands (copy), GUI tools, or opening an admin cmd.

Comment: This is elevation of a user account in Administrators; sudo is another thing.

Answer (score 0):

The following vbs script allows to launch a given command with arguments with elevation and mimics the behavior of the original unix `sudo` command for a limited set of used cases (it will not cache credentials nor it allows to truly execute commands with different credentials). I put it on `C:\Windows\System32`.

```vb
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
exe = objArgs(0)
args = ""
IF objArgs.Count >= 2 Then
   args = args & objArgs(1)
End If
For it = 2 to objArgs.Count - 1
   args = args & " " & objArgs(it)
Next
Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell")
windir=objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%WINDIR%")
Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShellApp.ShellExecute exe, args, "", "runas", 1
set objShellApp = nothing
```

Example use on a command prompt `sudo net start service`

Comment: Downvoters: еxplain why and what is not working for you. The script is tested and working for me.

Comment: This is elevation of a user account in Administrators; sudo is another thing.

Comment: @Massimo of course calling this script `sudo` is a small naming abuse: it doesn't and it will not have the same features of original `sudo`, but by default in unix will execute with super user (root) impersonification, providing this is allowed in `sudoers`, so the mimic of the provided example it's perfectly clear to me. It's not possible to create a full `sudo` replacement in Windows without access to Windows internals and without defining a clear semantic of what can and what can't be done by the command. If this quick and dirty script doesn't work for you should find a different solution

Answer (score -1):

Another option is [TakeCommand's](https://jpsoft.com/all-downloads/downloads.html) `START /ELEVATED …` switch.

The noninteractive (TCC-RT) version of the suite is offered for free.
The "sudo.btm" batch file would look like

```
@START "" /ELEVATED %*
```

which would also support the form `sudo /wait <someprogram> /params`

Answer (score -1):

The [scoop](https://scoop.sh/) creator has a [simple CLI](https://github.com/lukesampson/psutils/blob/master/sudo.ps1) that works great.

Install with: `scoop install sudo`

As expected, you need to click UAC dialog to elevate the new process.

```
$ sudo mkdir 'C:\Program Files\whatever'
                                                                                                                        
    Directory: C:\Program Files

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----           3/11/2024  2:47 PM                whatever
```