# In Windows 7, is it possible to do "runas" administrator *without* using the GUI?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, runas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is there any 'sudo' command for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows)

I'm aware of the various options for setting the Run as administrator flag, and for opening an elevated console window. But what if I have a normal console window, and I want to run a command as an administrator? The `runas` program doesn't seem to have an option that says

> Please don't show me some popup that I have to click on.

What I really want is something like `sudo` for Windows.

Comment: dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows

Comment: This isn't a dupe.  The OP is asking for how to spawn a process as an admin.  The Win32 term is "elevate".  Runas simply spawns a process as a different user.  Just like Linux, not all processes have "admin" permissions even though your user credentials have admin permissions.

Comment: Aye, I've basically solved the problem by just cutting back on my Windows use :)

Answer (score 1):

```
runas /user:domain\administrator commandtorun
```

Type `runas` on its own to see the full syntax.

[runas on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx)

The popup is Windows' User Account Control (UAC) technology, and you can't bypass it because it increases security by requiring user confirmation. This is similar to `sudo` requiring a password. You can disable UAC, just as you can enable password-less `sudo`. It's true that UAC isn't quite as configurable as `sudo` however.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.  There is only one account on the system (mine) which is id'ed as {first.lastname}.  It is already an admin account, but those privileges aren't enabled in a standard command line.  When I try to do 'runas /user:{machine}\{myname}, it just spits back usage text with no error message.  There doesn't seem to be an option for "elevate my privileges".  Doing "runas /user:[machine]\Administrator" produces the same response.

Comment: @Stabledog: Is the "Administrator" account enabled? Have you tried simply `runas /user:Administrator` (without machine or domain)?