# Elevate cmd to admin with command prompt?

Tags: windows-8, command-line, administrator

Is there anyway to enable administrator access instead of having to right click command prompt and run as administrator?

I tried runas /user:administrator CMD (prompts for password)
net user administrator /active:yes (System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied.)
runas /user:administrator luaexec.exe -w -f cmd.exe /k

This is on my local machine running windows 8 and have no passwords on any accounts

Comment: Wait... Do you want to elevate the current `cmd` or open a new, elevated one?

Comment: I think there is a **local security policy/directive** that doesn't allow administrator logins nor executions for account with no passwords. Maybe that is your problem? Saddly, I don't know what directive that is, I suppose it should be at `secpol.msc`. If you find it, please, report.

Comment: Is this method valid for you? http://superuser.com/questions/728810/how-do-you-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7-with-a-shortcut-key/728824#728824

Comment: I have used this other method, too, but it is shell programming. You could make a `.cmd` to call it with your desired parameters, if any: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944180/how-do-you-run-a-command-as-an-administrator-from-the-windows-shell

Comment: @Plasma - within the current cmd

Comment: @nhat That is not possible, see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/129034/elevate-a-running-program-to-administrator-windows-7) superuser question.

Comment: [Is there any 'sudo' command for Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/42537/241386)

Comment: Try `gsudo`: https://superuser.com/a/1499989/45898

Answer (score 5):

You can't change the permission from a current CMD.exe. You have to restart it. This is a Windows limitation. I use [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) with the [elevate switch](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/elevate.html) to start tools elevated.

Comment: no "su" equivalent then? heh. figures.

Comment: Completely forgot that was a feature of NirCmd. Any idea if this works on Windows 11 (I will http://tryitands.ee if you don't already know the answer)?
Alternatively, I've had pretty good luck with this, which uses powershell to launch an elevated Command Prompt in the current directory.
`powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process cmd \"/k cd /d %cd%\" -Verb RunAs" ` You might be able to elevate other processes the same way in Windows 11, just swapping out the name of the process after "Start-Process".

Answer (score 0):

It is not built in to Windows, but you could use the [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) command from PsTools:

```
psexec -h cmd
```

Comment: How to run this from usual (non-admin) CMD? Is it possible?

Comment: No it is not possible. `psexec` installs temporary service with `-h` and it requires admin privileges to do that... It is chick and egg problem. Just use `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` from Windows search results.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

1. Locate the command prompt (`cmd.exe`).
2. Right click on the file, go to **`Send To`** - **`Desktop (create shortcut)`**.
   [image]
3. Right click on the file again and go to **`Properties`**.
4. The target field put:

   > C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd
5. Open the shortcut, the following screen will be presented to you.
   [image]

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to run a script to update IP addresses and what's preventing the command from executing is the cmd.exe needs to be in admin. It would be time consuming to go to every computer to do this.