# Is it possible to shutdown a remote computer running Windows 7 via Telnet?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, permissions, shutdown, telnet

I've successfully connected to my Windows 7 desktop over wifi via Telnet from an XP Home netbook. To login, I use the following command:

```
telnet -l "win7desktop\win7user" win7desktop
```

`win7user` in this case is an Administrator on `win7desktop` and is also a member of the Telnet Clients Group.

The problem I have is that when I attempt to shut down `win7desktop` by issuing the following command:

```
shutdown /s
```

...at the Telnet prompt, I get an Access Denied error:

```
Access is denied.(5)
```

Is it possible to shutdown a remote computer running Windows 7 via Telnet? If so, what do I need to do to get around the Access is denied error?

Comment: You shouldn't use telnet, ever.  All data, including login credentials, are sent in the clear.

Comment: @Iszi unless you are on a closed network where that isn't an issue.

Comment: @Rob Unless said network is just a VM environment running on your own machine, and the VM network is not communicating with the host or other systems connected to the host, I wouldn't trust any network to be absolutely "closed" - especially one where credentials are being sent in the clear.

Answer (score 7):

Is it necessary to use telnet?

If not, you can use [PsShutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx) to shutdown a remote computer.  Or, you can use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and call the shutdown command.

```
psshutdown -u <username> -t 0 -k
psexec -d -u <username> shutdown -t 0 -s
```

Comment: If it's not possible with Telnet, I'll try one of these options, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting a permissions error.  As I understand it, even users who are Administrators sometimes need to elevate privileges to run certain commands.

You should try running the *shutdown* command with [***runas*** (aka *sudo for Windows*)](https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows):

```
runas /noprofile /user:Administrator shutdown /s
```

Comment: The win7desktop\win7user is an administrator on the target machine, do I therefore do runas /user:win7user ... ? Or do I need to explicitly say /user:Administrator ? (What would be the password for Administrator ?)

Comment: I've tried this with both /user:Administrator and /user:win7user, both with the same access denied error..

Answer (score 1):

There are certain cases where [Shutdown.exe does not work](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778327(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_7):

- The target computer has just restarted and is applying policies.
- A shut down of the target computer is in progress or has already occurred.
- The log on dialog box is open on the target computer.
- An expected or unexpected shutdown dialog box is open on the target
  computer.

Comment: None of these apply in this instance..

Answer (score 1):

To save others looking in future; I did all the Firewall, Local Security Policy guff, but no go. This is [the real trick for Win 7](http://www.emreakkas.com/windows-tips/remote-reboot-win32-access-is-denied-solution).

> Access is denied
>
> - All Windows flavors. The account you are executing the reboot command needs to be an Administrator on the machine that you are
>     trying to reboot. If you want to execute the shutdown command as a
>     different user, try psshutdown. The command will look like this when
>     specifying a user (where -r is for reboot and -u is for the user)
>
>   psshutdown 10.0.0.4 -r -u roger
> - In Windows XP, you will have to have “Simple File Sharing” disabled. Otherwise you will get the error message “Win 32: Access is denied”.
>     To disable simple file sharing launch a My Computer window.
>
>   From Tools menu select Folder Options, go to the View tab and remove
>     the check from “Use simple file sharing (Recommended)”.
> - In Windows 7 and Windows Vista, a small registry trick is needed. If you are getting the “Win32: Access is denied” message, launch a
>     registry editor (on the machine that you want to remotely reboot).
>
>   - Type regedit in the Run box
>   - Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESOFTWAREMicrosoftWindowsCurrentVersionPoliciesSystem
>   - Check the right side of the window to see if you have an entry for  LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy. If you do change its value to 1
>   - If the entry does not exist, right click, select New > DWORD (32-bit) Value and name it  LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy. Then double
>       click the new entry and change its value to 1
>   - Reboot your machine

Answer (score 0):

If you just typed `shutdown -i` in Windows 7 command prompt, then it prompts to remote shutdown dialog box.

It shows like a box containing

```
computer name : {add} 
                {remove}
                {browse}
```

and what you want this computer to do:

- restart
- logoff
- shutdown
- annotate unexpected shutdown

Then all you have to do is to fill it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
shutdown /f /s
```

or

```
shutdown /f /r
```

Don't use `/l`.