# How to run a command as administrator in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, elevation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there any ‘Sudo’ command for windows ?](https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows)

I want to run a console program in Windows, but it required administrative privileges. So, I can right click the command prompt to run as administrator, but I want to use something from the command line to elevate the program.

Is there something like `sudo` in Windows?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows

Comment: @Blorgbeard: My answer isn't in that other question, so not exactly a dup.

Answer (score 4):

Or use [runas](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html), supplied with Windows:

```
Runas /user:administrator notepad
```

Or you can have a batch file (say myrunas.bat) that contains:

```
Runas /user:administrator %*
```

%* means "all parameters".
Used, for example, as:

```
myrunas notepad
```