# What is the equivalent of sudo in Windows 7?

Tags: command-line, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there any 'Sudo' command for windows ?](https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows)

Is there a command line equivalent to sudo in Windows 7?  Or do you just have to open a command prompt that is being run as administrator?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The runas command is the equivelent of sudo in windows 7.

```
runas [{/profile|/noprofile}] [/env] [/netonly] [/smartcard] [/showtrustlevels] [/trustlevel] /user:UserAccountName program
```

Run the following command to start a command shell as an administrator. **EDIT**: Or you could right click the command prompt and click Run As Administrator.

```
runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd
```

Comment: I think it's quite common, but notice that `sudo` is different than `su` in the way that you can setup a `sudo` user to be able to only run a specific application as root with its own password, while `su` requires the user to enter the actual root password. `runas` is the same as `su`, not `sudo`.

Comment: Not an equivalent, runas does not allow as user to run a known application as superuser...

Comment: Hi @MUYBelgium, you are correct. I do know this now, but There is no other method for doing anything remotely close in Windows unfortunately. I do need something like this currently, but there is no solution. This is the closest method...

Comment: Sorry, this answer is just wrong. For *sudo* I could use my normal user password, just like on Windows if a program asks for elevated rights. In your example I need to know the admin password. Ergo, *runas* is by no means an equivalent for *sudo*.

Comment: This appears to be the closest thing to sudo in Windows. What option do you use as an equivalence to sudo while in Windows? If you look at the previous comments on the answer, you will see where I already addressed a similar opinion.

Answer (score 9):

[Runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28WS.10%29.aspx) is a pretty functional equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

It's easiest to run CMD as administrator (or elevated, in the case of standalone desktop Windows), but there is the [`runas`](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) command as well.

Answer (score 3):

The failure IMO with runas is that when used, you are "running as" a different user.
Different environment, different sets of defaults ...

A BIG TIME failure for me.

[SuRun - SUDO in Windows](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/surun.html) states:

> The best part is - SuRun will elevate the privileges for the CURRENT
>   user account! It will not try to run programs as another,
>   administrator account. This means all registry entries and file system
>   paths will be correct, just as the user expects them!

(I have not tried it - yet.  Cannot believe they way MS has implemented elevation & that I may have to resort to a third party program to have things work they way they should have in the first place.)