# su Command Prompt

Tags: command-line, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any 'sudo' command for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows)

Commands `su` & `sudo` could be used to turn whole current terminal session as super user with administration privileges.

**What**'s the corresponding command of Windows CMD ?

I know that I can start CMD as administrator by

- Right click & Start as Administrator
- Typing CMD in start search bar the `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`

But I want to evaluate this permission from inside CMD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent in Windows is the "runas" command, it is similar to the "sudo" command in unix/linux but you have to specify the user as well. A typical example would be:

```
runas /user:mymachine\administrator [command]
```

If your user is is an Administrator you can use your own username like so:

```
runas /user:myusername ipconfig
```

To elevate an entire command prompt just put "cmd" in as the command to run, ie:

```
runas /user:myusername cmd
```

There may be other ways of doing this, but this is the way I've done it for years and have seen done in corporate scripted environments.

Comment: runas is more like su than sudo. Sudo will attempt to run your command as super user. su is akin to `switch user`. With runas you can execute commands as a lower privilege user if desired.