# Start runas in an interactive mode

Tags: windows, runas

I would like to use the runas tool to start a program as if someone [Shift]-[RightClick]ed a Link and choose "Run as different user" - is that possible?

runas.exe itself does not have matching parameter set for this use-case.

Comment: Yes this is indeed possible. There are several questions on this very website that explain how to do it, most of course, point to the documentation for the `runas` ( http://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows) command.

Comment: I was hoping there is some out of the box method to do so... but apparently that is not the case.

Comment: What do you consider to be "out of the box" because a built-in command seems "out of the box" solution to me.  Most people do not launch applications as another user.

Comment: So perhaps I missed something, but Shift-Rightclick opens a window asking me for credentials - runas will not do that.