# How to give a single software administrative rights in a guest user on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator

In my internet cafe, is a software which requires administrative rights. But the computers will automatically start on a guest form. But its kinda tiring to turn 50 pc on every morning, open in administrator, turn the software on then switch to the guest user.

But I was thinking, if I give that specific software administrative rights, even tho the guest account is open.

Is it possible to be done? if so, then how can I do that?

Comment: Need more detail. You can do something like that but need to know exactly where the package resides and what about it needs administrative rights to run. To start... what error do you get when you try running it as "Guest"? Have you contacted the software manufacturer?

Comment: not really, but in the EULA it specifies that the software requires administrator privileges for all the functions to run.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command prompt.(problem with this, it still will ask for a password. I'll find a better way.)

Use `runas /noprofile /user:Administrator {PROGRAM NAME}` where {PROGRAM NAME} is the name of the program.(see [source](https://superuser.com/a/42540/645299))

You could then create a script and save it as a file that you run. See [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/263177/how-to-write-a-batch-script-on-windows/)(How To Geek) or [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-simple-batch-bat-file/)(Make Use Of) for how to convert it into a script, or .bat file.

Now all you need to do is double click on a file.

Comment: Wouldn't this as written require the user authenticate as the Administrator user since the Administrator users's password is not passed on?

Comment: yes. ramhound is right, its the same as putting the software shortcut in "on startup" folder, or something like that. it will require for the user to type the password