# Switch user in Windows command line

Tags: cmd.exe, su

Is there a similar Linux **su** command in Windows command line?
If not, what about:

- in Powershell?;
- a workaround with a *.vbs script?;
- a workaround with some of the sysinternals tools like "psexec.exe"?

Note: I am using a netcat remote shell connection, so I am not able to insert password when requested by command "runas".

Note2: "sudo" and "su" commands are different commands. "sudo" executes commands as another user. "su" changes the effective user.

Note3: Despite finding an answer to my specific issue, The answer to this question, as mentioned by @Ramhound is "not possible"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any 'sudo' command for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows)

Comment: @Ramhound "sudo" and "su" commands are different commands. "sudo" executes commands as another user. "su" changes the effective user. People are trying to show me a work around with "runas" which would be the "sudo" from linux. But my main question is about "su", which would be switch the user.

Comment: @f4d0 - If you cannot use `runas` then what you want is not possible.

Comment: If you want SU use runas to start a command prompt as a different user. every command in there is then run as that other user.

Comment: @LPChip I am not using the windows directly. I am connected to windows using a netcat reverse shell. I got to this shell through an exploit that took advantage of a vulnerability from a program executed by a different user than the one I want to login now. But this is already too far away from our discussion. It's not possible is an acceptable answer, I'll search for another solution. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: How about sysinternals tool psExec? You have already mentioned it in your questions and it also supports passing password through command line. Have you already tried that?

Comment: @Sandeep just before i read your answer, i solved my issue with psexec.exe 
I was able to execute locally a set of commands with user and password and get a shell with the desired user :)

Comment: Consider adding your own answer with thorough detail of what you did exactly to resolve to keep this post helpful to others that may be looking for a similar solution as you describe.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows you have the `runas` command. Try this:

1. Navigate to c:\windows\system32.
2. Enter the following command: runas
   /user:computer_name\account_name explorer.exe

Comment: I need to use password as well... I am using a netcat session that does not allow me to insert the password.

Comment: @f4d0 runas can also allow you to set the password.

Comment: @LPChip i cannot find out how! Can you please post an answer with that solution?

Comment: Doesnt it ask you for a password?

Comment: @f4d0 see the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811209/how-to-supply-password-to-runas-command-when-executing-it-from-java

Comment: @LukasGermerott yes it does, but because of the shell i am on, the execution finishes before i am able to insert password. In other words, it does not stop to allow me to insert the password, it just flashes through it and finishes execution.

Comment: @LPChip echo with pipes or redirection with files doesn't work with "runas" command: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041129-00/?p=37183/

Comment: @f4d0 that post is from 2004, while mine is from 2012. Have you actually tried it exactly like it was mentioned in that answer?

Comment: @LPChip exactly no, because I am trying from the command line, not from java execution. :) But taking out the java stuff including character escape, yes, i am doing it like using a normal echo to pipe it to the next command. I am studying penetration testing, i do echo's at least 50 times a day :)))

Comment: there's a huge difference in doing `echo "stuff" | runas` vs `cmd /C echo "stuff" | runas`

Comment: @LPChip i didn't know about that there was a difference. Thanks for the attention. Anyway, i try it, and still not working. I really appreciate your effort in trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
user@server C:\Windows\System32> runas /user:Administrator "dir C:\Users\Administrator"
```

So something like **runas /user:MyUser "command"**